# How would I go about answering the following questions on the determinants of matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, algebra-precalculus, determinant

"1) If the determinant of a 5 x 5 matrix A is det(A) = 8, and the matrix B is obtained from A by multiplying the second row by 2, then det(B) = ?

2) If the determinant of a 4 x 4 matrix A is det(A) = 5, and the matrix C is obtained from A by swapping the third and fourth rows, then det(C) = ?

3) If the determinant of a 5 x 5 matrix A is det(A) = 6, and the matrix D is obtained from A by adding 4 times the third row to the second, then det(D) = ?"

My problem is not getting the new determinant but rather finding a matrix that satisfies the original determinant. Is there a formula through which I can find the matrix given its determinant, because computing the determinant of the new matrix should not be a problem.

Thank you!

Comment: You don't need to find the matrix $A$; it could be any arbitrary matrix with the given determinant. If you really want to find one just make a diagonal matrix.

Comment: The whole point of these questions is to check whether you know how the *elementary row transformations* affect the determinant.

Comment: @DevSR This resource may be a quick point of reference for you to understand these questions: http://linear.ups.edu/html/section-PDM.html make sure you understand how and why these rules apply by understanding what a determinant really represents.

Comment: @userSeventeen That link was very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

*Hint*

In 1), we have
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0&0\\0&0&1&0&0\\0&0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&0&1\end{pmatrix}A$$

Can you solve the other parts in a similar way?